# There is a blank area on the screen(IOS)

Tags: react-native

Description

RN version

0.73.4

Description

When my program was running on iOS emulators and real phones, I found that the screen was not fully occupied, and there were rotation and zoom buttons in the bottom right corner of the program

Code

```
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import {screenSize} from './utils/tools';
export default function Main() {
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(screenSize);
},[])
return (

      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle={'light-content'} />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
            <Text>{screenSize.width}</Text>
            <Text>{screenSize.height}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>


);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
},
});
```

Image:

[image]

When my program was running on iOS emulators and real phones, I found that the screen was not fully occupied, and there were rotation and zoom buttons in the bottom right corner of the program.

Comment: That looks like an iPad simulator for an iPhone app

Comment: It looks like it is, but I didn't make any other judgments, I just created a new demo

Comment: does the `Info.plist` specify it supports iPad as well?

Comment: I have already added it，but it still doesn't seem to have changed much
<key>UISupportedDevices</key>
  <array>
      <string>iPhone</string>
      <string>iPad</string>
  </array>

Answer (score 0):

React Native only targets iPhone by default, if you run on an iPad, it will show up as a scaled app. This is your case.

You have to change the xcode project to build it as a universal app.
Find the Deployment Info section of the General tab in the app target and switch that from iPhone to Universal.

Hope it helps!